# Confusion about Bool var and func naming convention in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, refactoring, naming-conventions

I am developing iOS/Swift app. I am confused after seeing `Bool` variables and function naming convention provided by Google (https://google.github.io/swift/). Because Swift itself follows simple adverbed which is not mentioned in Googles suggestion i.e.

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945493-contains

What should be the proper way of naming a func that returns Bool?

```
Option 1. matches(string: String) -> Bool
Option 2. isMatched(string: String) -> Bool
```

I prefer myself naming it as `matches` but my team members want to name it as `isMatched`.

Comment: Definitely **Option 1**.

Comment: Option 2. is unclear, the `isSomething` works well when it is used for properties but is less relevant for methods because of arguments. For instance, `newCandidate.matches(string: requirement)` is way clearer than `newCandidate.isMatched(string: requirement)`. Also, for Option 1. you should remove the label with `_`: `matches(_ string: String) -> Bool` so that you obtain a nice `newCandidate.matches(requirement)`. If using Option 2, a nice typo would be `isMatched(with string: String) -> Bool`.

Comment: Option 1 and I would also add an underscore to allow you to omit the string naming parameter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## From the [**Swift** API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#boolean-assertions)

> Uses of Boolean methods and properties should read as assertions about the receiver when the use is nonmutating, e.g. `x.isEmpty`, `line1.intersects(line2)`.

So both of them are **correct**. The Foundation also uses both: e.g.

```
12.isMultiple(of: 2)
[12].contains(2)

// and more e.g.
"accept".hasPrefix("a")
```

The only thing matters is to be read correctly.